# Connection between smop and networkx - different errors depending on versions of networkx

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda

I am new to python, and I found a matlab code online that I want to convert to python code using smop.
I've installed smop, however when I try to run it I get an error.

When I have networkx version 1.11 I get the following error trying to run `smop main.m`

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\envs\smop\lib\site-packages\smop\main.py", line 66, in main
    G = resolve.resolve(stmt_list)
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\envs\smop\lib\site-packages\smop\resolve.py", line 54, in resolve
    u = G.node[n]["ident"]
AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'node'
Errors: 1
```

When I install a later version of networkx (`pip install networkx==2.0` or `pip install networkx==2.5`) I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\Scripts\smop.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smop\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import resolve
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smop\resolve.py", line 22, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    import networkx.generators
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\generators\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from networkx.generators.classic import *
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\generators\classic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators import complete_bipartite_graph
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from networkx.algorithms.dag import *
  File "C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\dag.py", line 14, in <module>
    from fractions import gcd
ImportError: cannot import name 'gcd' from 'fractions' (C:\Users\IDABUK\Anaconda3\lib\fractions.py)
```

I am running this from the anaconda prompt window (anaconda power shell?).

Is there a way to fix this?
The only solutions I find online are people installing various networkx-versions which does not seem like a solution for me in this case, or changing 'node' to 'nodes' directly in the code, however I can't find any instances of 'nodes' in the matlab code.

Answer (score 0):

For people in the future looking for an answer:
I could not find an answer for this.

However it worked using matlab2python.
This is how it worked for me:
In the terminal I wrote

```
git clone https://github.com/ebranlard/matlab2python
cd matlab2python
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and then I used this code to convert each matlab-script:

```
python matlab2python/matlab2python.py file.m -o file.py
```

Comment: It seems like it would be more informative to know what the output of the matlab2python conversion was, i.e. what the actual solution is using Python without having to go via an intermediate program